# Validation on column between 2 values

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, validation, column-validation, formula

I am using SharePoint 2016.

In a list, I created a column `hostname` of type single line of text.

I would like to limit the values between `r000xxx` and `r399xxx` where (x= any letter).

What's the right formula ?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Column Validation Examples for your reference:

https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html